# TCP client with multiple processes

Tags: c, sockets

Before asking my question let me inform you all that I am novice in the field of Network Programming so please pardon my mistakes and suggest ways to improve. Thank you in advance!

For an assignment in my network programming class our professor wants us to write a client program which makes use of fork() i.e.

```
pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) // child
Send();
else //parent
Recv();
```

And the code I am attempting is as follows,

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <error.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define SERVER_PORT_NUM "10060"
#define MAX_BYTES 2000
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

int status;
struct addrinfo hints;
struct addrinfo *servinfo;
char buf[MAX_BYTES];

memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

if ( (status = getaddrinfo("localhost", SERVER_PORT_NUM, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
return 2;
}

int s;
if ((s = socket(servinfo->ai_family, servinfo->ai_socktype, servinfo->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "socket: %s\n", gai_strerror(s));
    return 2;
}

if (connect(s, servinfo->ai_addr, servinfo->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
    close(s);
}

freeaddrinfo(servinfo);

char ch='\0';
pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) {// child process
    while(1){
        memset(&buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
        scanf("%s",buf);
        send(s,buf,strlen(buf),0);

    }

}//pid==0

else { //parent process
    int numbytes=0;
    memset(&buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
    while(1) {
        if((numbytes= recv(s, &buf, MAX_BYTES-1, 0)) >0) {
        printf("\n%s", buf);
        memset(&buf, 0, numbytes);
        }

        if(numbytes < 0) {
            printf("Error receiving data");
        }

    }

}

close(s);
return 0;
}
```

I want to send data to server only if there is some input from user on client terminal and display on client terminal if there is any data from server. Right now, after getting data once from server it is hanging. What can be the best condition for termination of sending and receiving data to/from server?

Answer (score 0):

For the part to ensure write occurs only after reads, one way is to use.

```
wait(NULL);
```

is the call used by a parent to wait for child process to terminate. Any code executed after this is guaranteed to run after child is terminated.

Perhaps you should reverse your order i.e. parent should be writing and child should be reading.

However, this means all of your writes are done after client has completed reading and terminated.

If you want to read one complete line, the write and back to reading again, above is not the way to go.

Comment: Hello there,

Thank you for your reply.

I don't want one process to terminate and then other process to start. I want to do what you mentioned in the last line- read one complete line write if user has anything to send and then back to read again.

Comment: Okay the weird part in that requirement is, you want one process to effectively do nothing until another one receives data. Usually this is either done with a single process i.e. both reads and writes since ordering is required. Otherwise both parent and child proceed independently.

Comment: One mechanism that i can suggest though seems over kill but should work nevertheless is to use a pipe. See you need a way for child to indicate to parent that i am done with one read. So they need an IPC (inter process communication) mechanism. A pipe is shared between a parent and child, the child would read data until some sort of message terminator for a single message is received for e.g. \n, a fixed length is achieved. Then it writes on the pipe. The parent meanwhile is busy waiting to read data on pipe, once data is available (just an indication that child is done reading) it would send

Comment: Okay I think I will go ahead with IPC. Thank you for your suggestion. 
I was debugging the code I feel I am unable to send data to server. But I unable to figure out why is it so. Any views on where I maybe doing wrong?
Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: what is the return value of your send call? It should return number of bytes written. I hope you have a separate server application listening on the specific port. "feel i am unable" doesn't help at all. Tell what happens specifically

Comment: I am sorry for being vague. The thing is above code does not work because either of the process goes in infinite loop. For the 1st time my server application which is running on specific port asks me question and when I enter my answer, nothing happens. I checked the number of bytes send() returns and it is returning correctly for the 1st time but as there is no response from server I assumed I might be making some error in send() but maybe the case that my recv() is not working properly after 1st time - I am clueless as it just hangs.